# Javascript: Access Hidden Text Field by ID does not work on this site. Any idea why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Need to fill a textfield from a form but can't access the field. My script repeats all 6 seconds so as soon as the input field is visible it should be found?

Any idea?  Thanks everyone

**script:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var a = document.getElementById("field_7");
var b = document.getElementById("postbox-container-1");
if(a)
  console.log("field_7 exists");
else
  console.log("field_7 does not exist"); 
if(b)
  console.log("postbox-container-1 exists");
else
  console.log("postbox-container-1 does not exist");

setTimeout(arguments.callee, 6000);

})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="required zip-code control-group active valid">
<label class="control-label" for="field_7">Postal code / ZIP</label>
<div class="controls" name="controls"><input maxlength="10" type="text" id="field_7"></div></div>
```

[image: After Page load the input field is hidden but available in the code]

[image: After a Button Click the input field is visible but still can't be fetched with ym script which repeats all 6 seconds]

Comment: Is the field display hidden, or display none?

Comment: Hello Martin. From the html code, none of both. BUT the fields are not in the viewport and only show after pressing a button - probably some Ajax. I do see the elements inspector tho.

Comment: Does your logs confirm they exist, like shown in your code example?

Comment: An approach similar to this will not work for you? https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/OJgYRJJ

Comment: The element #fulfillomat which is available and visible right after page load is confirmed but the #field_7 which is only visible after the click of a button not. The address fields i need to access are within a "stepped checkout process" on that page loaded into a sidebar on the right. But as said, in the element inspector i see the field_7 after page load. Really strange as i have done similar things many time s and can't get it to work here. Thank you

Comment: is it possible for you to move the function into whichever AJAX file is injected after after the button click? That way both elements should be visible and it should work (without any setTimeout hocus pocus.)

Comment: No, i don't have access to this site and i'm only a user there. I need to fill in the address fields with a script but can't access these input fields for some reason. I do have a test login to that site if someone is interested to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237765/discussion-between-gto-and-martin).